# Are Hyper-V IDE and SCSI devices performance equal?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

Do Hyper-V IDE and SCSI devices both offer equally fast I/O performance when integration services are installed in the guest operating system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Microsoft

> Although the I/O performance of physical SCSI and IDE devices can
>   differ significantly, this is not true for the virtualized SCSI and
>   IDE devices in Hyper-V. Hyper-V. IDE and SCSI devices both offer
>   equally fast I/O performance when integration services are installed
>   in the guest operating system.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183729(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: How can that technically be given that IDE drives per API do only allow one outstanding operation at the same time, while SCSI allows more?

Comment: Oh no!, I attached two Disks (IDE and SCSI) for every VM I created so far. and now you mean it was a wast of time? I had Linux Integration Services installed on all of them.

Comment: @TomTom I don't know, Hyper-V isn't my bread and butter, but the source link is directly from TechNet.

Comment: Yes, I know. Still this is like some paper sying "1+1=3" - it makes no sense. Point. Even with full driver support, as long as the OS thinks it is a IDE drive, it is bound by the limitations. Now any pro wil ltell you that SAS is better than SATA ALSO because SATA is limited to 32 outstanding commands, SAS to 2 billion (theoreitcal limit of hte protocol obviously) and SAN's often ahve 200+ outstanding commands. IDE is protocol limited to IIRC exactly ONE. That means a lot less IO the VM can send to the host for processing.

Comment: My assumption here is that Microsoft is trying to say "the virtual drives are effectively limited by the underlying storage".  Also note the caveat "`when integration services are installed in the guest operating system`", which leads me to believe that Microsoft is supplying some additional magic with the integration services package.  Bottom line: As with all performance claims, ***test it yourself*** - manufacturers/vendors lie like dogs.

Comment: So what do you suggest? should we attach SCSI disk or just stick with IDE because it makes no difrence ?

Comment: You can only have up to 4 IDE disks (two controllers, two disks each) in a Hyper-V guest, so for that reason (not necessarily performance) it would appear that SCSI is usually the best bet for non-boot devices.

Comment: The "SCSI adapter" doesn't actually speak SCSI. It speaks MS Storage Filter API only. The IDE device actually speaks both IDE and the API; once a machine had loaded the drivers necessary for the APIs to function both storage mechanisms work exactly the same. The "IDE Adapter" can't hot-swap drives like the "SCSI" one because of the legacy IDE requirements. They added both types of storage controllers so you could choose your trade-off: Bootable or Hot-Swappable.

Comment: @ChrisS Why couldn't MS just say that somewhere instead of letting us think that their technical writers were trolling us?

Comment: @MichaelHampton There's **a lot** of that stuff in Hyper-V. I'd swear they hired the best, more competent people to write the software. Then the managers got angry because the software was full of "technical mumbo jumbo" so the managers had the names all rewritten. You're lucky they didn't have to use car analogy terms.

Comment: @ChrisS Haha, hm, in that case it might be beyond my ability to understand the documentation. I think I'll stick with VMware and KVM until they do something about that problem. :)